# net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING with OPTIONS request

Tags: php, google-chrome, nginx, http-post, http-options-method

I'm using nginx (1.9.3) + php-fpm (via unix sockets) with another nginx as a reverse proxy. And rarely (1 out of ~100 requests) I get `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` during `OPTIONS` XHR request from one subdomain to another (cloud.example.com to api.example.com). This OPTIONS request sent automatically before POST. Chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) OS X

Reverse proxy:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Request headers:

```
  OPTIONS /my/request/uri HTTP/1.1
  Host: api.example.com
  Connection: keep-alive
  Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
  Origin: https://subdomain.example.com
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
  Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
  Accept: */*
  Referer: https://subdomain.example.com/
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
```

Response headers:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 06:39:05 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://subdomain.example.com
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
```

My guess is that this could be caused by timeouts, but I doubt there are milliseconds timeouts somewhere. The screenshot below is from a Chrome developer tools network tab filtered by the same request repeated many times.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome developer tools / Network]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with Firefox 43.0.4 OS X after ~500 POST requests

Comment: And I still can't figure out how to reproduce this error even in Chrome. Sometimes I don't get this error even after 1000+ POST requests